# VS 2010 C# file has no errors but when I debug says it can't find a mystery file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

The error is

> Could not find file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\no'.

and it arises from form1.cs with a line that reads:

```
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.IMG)).EndInit();
```

VS generated this code from my choices in design view, because I never manually edited this file. I don't have any idea what that file is and I never attempted to call it or use it what's going on with this? why did try to open a file never did anything with at all? Since I never did anything with this file that I never mentioned in my code I assume Visual Studio added this? Why? What is it? How do I fix this? For clarification, that file does not exist.

Comment: That's the location where the compiled files go.  If you have one project that reference another then the referenced one will get compiled to it's bin directory and the other project will attempt to read the compiled files there.  Typically when you see a missing file in the bin directory the first thing to try is a clean and rebuild of the solution.

Comment: ? I know thats where they go but i never did anything with that file on any project and i dont know what it is or why it is trying to call it? I even tried making a new project and rebuilt my form and pasted my code but it still does things that make no sense to me

Answer (score -1):

I think you've done something strange. It's to do with a Debug build.

Right click Solution > Clean Solution. This will remove all the obj and bin folders.

*I suspect you may get an error doing this, a file lock from Visual Studio. If so, close Visual Studio and manually delete the obj and bin folders.*

Now try F5 to run the project.

---

If the above fails, delete the Control called IMG in your form1.cs and F5. If you can't from the designer, go to the form1.designer.cs file and manually remove the references to the IMG control.